# The volume of the curve $3-x^2=y$ rotated around the x axis using shell method

Tags: calculus, integration

So I've been trying all night and every time I get a different answer. All I know is that the integral will be multiplied by $2$. Is the equation in terms of $y$? Is the $a=0$, $b=3$?

There is a question connected to it that asks the same question but it is only the portion of the graph in quadrant $1$ rotated around the $x$-axis.

So I tried $a=0, b=3$ the formula was
$$\int_{0}^{3} 2\pi y\sqrt{3-y}~dy$$
Then I tried $a=-\sqrt{3}, b=+\sqrt{3}$. The integral was
$$\int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}} 2\pi y\sqrt{3-y}~dy$$

Comment: Could you share some of the attempts you have tried? We can help you better, when we can see, where the problem is.

Comment: So I tried a=0, b=3 the formula was the integral of 2pi(y)(sqrt(3-y))dy
 Then I tried a=-sqrt3, b=+sqrt3. The integral was 2pi(y)(sqrt(3-y))dy

Comment: So you got different answers when putting in different values? But that is how it's supposed to be, are you sure, you made a mistake somewhere? (By the way, here is a tutorial for MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you wish to rotate the region bounded by the curve and the $x$-axis around the $x$-axis, in which case the volume is $V = 2\int_{0}^{3} 2\pi y\sqrt{3 - y}~dy$ using the shell method.   The limits are $0$ and $3$ since you are integrating with respect to $y$.  You can check your answer by using the disc method, which gives $V = 2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}} \pi(3 - x^2)^2~dx$.  Here the limits are $0$ and $\sqrt{3}$ since you are integrating with respect to $x$.  In both cases, I opted to use symmetry to double the region in the first quadrant.